# Undefined is not a function: call to fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to get fancybox to work on a site right now, but I keep getting an undefined error. I am not sure if there is a conflict with the jQuery library being used on the site for if there is something missing from the fancybox plugin.

This is the bit of code that is producing the undefined error:

```
   $.fancybox({
            'title': 'Request Information',
            'autoDimensions': true,
            'width': width,
            'height': height,
            'titlePosition': 'inside',
            'href': url
        });
```

It's the $.fancybox bit that is triggering the error. I am calling what I believe to be the necessary css and js files to run the plugin: 
jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css (inside the head tag)
jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js (before the closing body tag)

What am I missing?

This is the order in which the scripts are being called on the site:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/BirdTech.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/magictable.js">
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you make sure you included jquery before including fancybox? Can you post the HTML snippet showing the script tags?

Comment: Where's the call to jquery itself?

Comment: what's the value of `url` in `'href': url`?